# Nautilus folders bar looks ugly... only in folder view

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus, kde-4

I'm using KDE, and I like Nautilus, so I chose it as the default folder viewer. In the folder view, the buttons that take me to previous folders look like this, which is ugly:

[image]

But in Firefox, in the Upload file dialog, it looks fine!

[image]

Can this be fixed so that it would look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two screenshots is that your version of Nautilus uses GTK+ 3.x for its graphical interface, while Firefox uses the file chooser from GTK+ 2.x, and these GTK versions use incompatible theme formats. Your current GTK theme doesn't support GTK3, so you're seeing the built-in default (aka "Raleigh").

Install the `gnome-themes-standard` package, then edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=Adwaita
```

Comment: Starting with GTK 3.14, Adwaita will become the built-in default, so programs shouldn't be ugly by default anymore.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. Except that the file settings.ini didn't exist, and I had to create it.

Comment: Yes, that's normal...